# Adding menu title to custum URL

Tags: menus, url-rewriting

I want to customize  my url rewriting this way : urlhome/MenuTitle/PageTitle. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Where does the menu title come from? Have you tried setting up parent/child pages?

Comment: it answers my questions! thank you for saving my day ! :)